# not able to see In app purchase test user on Clicking of Manage user

Tags: app-store-connect

i want to set up a test account to test in app purchase on sandbox,  i am logging into intunes connect and following the same procedure as prescribed in the itunes connect developer guide. i am clinking on manage user, but i am not able to see the window where i can select test in app purchase user.

do i need to do any change in my profile to make it visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just didn't had the paid app contract certificate so wasn't getting the page
now it is working fine... In case anybody is stuck in this, check it once.